# Security: password check removal and custom User Provider

Tags: symfony

I'm creating Symfony2 (Version 2.0.16) `custom User Provider` to work with our LDAP Server, but according [How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) document, password checking is done on Symfony2 side:

> When a user submits a username and password, the authentication layer
>   asks the configured user provider to return a user object for a given
>   username. Symfony then checks whether the password of this user is
>   correct and generates a security token so the user stays authenticated
>   during the current session.

First of all I don't like the idea of passing User passwords back to Symfony. Secondly, we already have LDAP Web Service which checks if password matched on its side and changing it would be problematic.

**Question:** How can remove password checking from Symfony and let it rely on LDAP Web 
Service which returns Boolean `IsAuth` flag?

This how I query LDAP Web Service now:

```
// The output has IsAuth flag
$this->get('LDAP_user_provider')
  ->searchMember($request->get('username'), $request->get('password'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this is not super trivial, but I'll try to give you as much information as possible. There are some small changes you need to do for Symfony 2.0, my solution is for 2.1. I hope there are no copy/paste problems, and no typos or missing configuration. First, you will want to create a `AuthenticationProvider`, something like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactory;

use Beryllium\CacheBundle\Cache;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\RestToken;

/**
 * The Provider is the component of the authentication system that authenticates tokens.
 */
class LdapProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
    private $userProvider;
    private $encoderFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     * @param String                $cacheDir
     * @param EncoderFactory        $encoderFactory
     */
    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider, EncoderFactory $encoderFactory)
    {
        $this->userProvider   = $userProvider;
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory; // usually this is responsible for validating passwords
    }

    /**
     * This function authenticates a passed in token.
     * @param  TokenInterface          $token
     * @return TokenInterface
     * @throws AuthenticationException if wrong password or no username
     */
    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (!empty($token->username)) {
            $user    = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->username);
            $encoder = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user);

            if ($token->needsAuthentication && !$token->isLdapAuthenticated()) {
                throw new AuthenticationException('Password wrong');
            }
        } else {
            throw new AuthenticationException('No user');
        }

        $token->setUser($user);
        $token->setAuthenticated(true);

        return $token;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @param  TokenInterface $token
     * @return Boolean
     */
    public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token instanceof RestToken;
    }
}
```

Register the service (with XML):

```
    <service id="ldap.security.authentication.provider"
      class="Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\LdapProvider" public="false">
        <argument /> <!-- User Provider -->
        <argument type="service" id="security.encoder_factory"/>
    </service>
```

Or with YAML:

```
   ldap.security.authentication.provider:
       class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\LdapProvider
       public: false
       arguments:
           - ~
           - "@security.encoder_factory"
```

Create a Security Factory:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Factory;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\DefinitionDecorator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\NodeDefinition;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\SecurityFactoryInterface;

class LdapFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
    public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
    {
        $providerId = 'security.authentication.provider.ldap.'.$id;
        $container
            ->setDefinition($providerId, new DefinitionDecorator('ldap.security.authentication.provider'))
            ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider))
        ;

        $listenerId = 'security.authentication.listener.ldap.'.$id;
        $listener   = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('ldap.security.authentication.listener'));

        return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'pre_auth';
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'ldap';
    }

    public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
    {}
}
```

and register it in you Bundle:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Factory\LdapFactory;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
        $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new LdapFactory());
    }
}
```

and create your own token:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Token;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken;

/**
 * This is a class that represents a security token that is used for logged in users.
 */
class LdapToken extends AbstractToken
{
    public $sessionId;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $member;
    public $needsAuthentication = true;

    public function __construct(array $roles = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($roles);
    }

    public function getCredentials()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        if ($this->getUser()) {
            return $this->getUser()->getRoles();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }

    public function isLdapAuthenticated()
    {
         return true; // Left as an exercise
    }
}
```

Then you need to create that Token in a listener, something like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Security\Firewall;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ListenerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

use Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\LdapToken;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\AttributeBag;

/**
 * Class that will listen for log ins and then authorize the user.
 */
class LdapListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    /**
     * A security context
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    protected $securityContext;

    /**
     * A authentication manager that we will be able to authenticate against
     * @var AuthenticationManagerInterface
     */
    protected $authenticationManager;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param SecurityContextInterface              $securityContext
     * @param AuthenticationManagerInterface        $authenticationManager
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext,
        AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager
    ) {
        $this->securityContext              = $securityContext;
        $this->authenticationManager        = $authenticationManager;
    }

    /**
     * This function is handling the authentication part.
     *
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     * @return
     */
    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $token = new LdapToken();

        // now populate it with whatever information you need, username, password...

        try {
            $returnValue = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);

            if ($returnValue instanceof TokenInterface) {
                if ($token->needsAuthentication) {
                    if ($event->hasResponse()) {
                        $response = $event->getResponse();
                    } else {
                        $response = new Response();
                        $event->setResponse($response);
                    }
                }

                return $this->securityContext->setToken($returnValue);
            } elseif ($returnValue instanceof Response) {
                return $event->setResponse($response);
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            // Do nothing in this case. We are returning a 401 below
        }

        $response = new Response('UNAUTHORIZED');
        $response->setStatusCode(HTTPCodes::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

and register that as a service as well (using XML):

```
    <service id="ldap.security.authentication.listener"
      class="Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Firewall\RestListener" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
        <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.manager" />
    </service>
```

or YAML:

```
    ldap.security.authentication.listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\Firewall\RestListener
        public: false
        arguments: 
            - "@security.context"
            - "@security.authentication.manager"
```

Hope that gets you started!

Comment: Oh, that's a lot of effort! Trying it... Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide me the YAML version of the services, thanks in advance

Comment: @nusje2000 I added the YAML service configuration to my answer